# Detached element not found even after being inserted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an element with id=`search`.
I try to detach the element from a `<td>` and insert it on another `<td>`, but it just happens the first time, then gives `undefined`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.select-area', function () {
    var element = $('#search').detach();

    $('tr[id_area="' + parseInt($(this).attr('area-id')) + '"]')
        .find('td:eq(1)')
        .html('<div id="search">' + element.html() + '</div>');
});
```

How can I make this happen also for subsequent clicks on `.select-area`?
Thank you very much for help

Comment: technically you are appending a new element, not the detached one. Just append element.

Comment: Why `detach()` and not `remove()`? `detach()` keeps all of the event handlers around, and the way you're inserting the HTML you lose those anyway...

Comment: @epascarello is it about `append()`. It was a mistake, I am using `html()`. Thanks for you time

Comment: @HereticMonkey,  I need the HTML that is inside that element, to move it elsewhere so that I re-use it. I didn't use `remove` as I think it will destroy that HTML. wdyt?

Comment: `remove` doesn't "destroy that HTML"; it's still available via `element.html()`, it's just detached from the DOM. See [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried it to no avail. I don't know why I don't find this info in docs!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of sharing, a solution to my problem was to move the detach operation outside of the click event listener. It seems logical since this operation need to be only done one time in my case.

```
// On document ready
var element = $('#search').detach();
$('body').on('click', '.select-area', function () {
    $('tr[id_area="' + parseInt($(this).attr('area-id')) + '"]')
        .find('td:eq(1)')
        .html('<div id="search">' + element.html() + '</div>');
});
```

But the approach mentioned by epascarello is more simple, and should be taken from beginning. It just doens't fit my specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Just select it and append it to the new location. The element will be moved, events will remain.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'td.select-area', function () {
    var element = $('#search');
    $(this)
        .closest("tr")
        .find('td:eq(1)')
        .append(element);
});

$("#test").on("input", function (e) {
  console.log(e.originalEvent.data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="select-area">1</td>
    <td><span id="search"><input id="test" /></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td class="select-area">2</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="select-area">3</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="select-area">4</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="select-area">5</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This really sounds a better approach and contains some new info. I don't know why it doesn't work in my scenario. In fact I am clicking on elements outside the table (so I can't use $(this)). Also I am using a data attribute to serve as <tr> identifier. I will keep trying your approach, thanks sir

Comment: The $(this) should make no difference, it is just the quick way to make a demo.Maybe if you make a small demo of your issue we can give you a better answer.

Comment: I really appreciate sir. I will do a demo (its been a while didn't use SO tools or similar). Good idea, again thanks

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, I have posted an answer, I hope it explains a bit the problem